# Use mouse scroll on div to trigger animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, mouseevent

```
<div class="page">
      div content
</div>

<script>

if( scroll mouse up while hovering #page )
$('.page').animate({'left':'+40px'});

if( scroll mouse down while hovering #page )
$('.page').animate({'left':'-40px'});

</script>
```

I want to do something like the example above. Can someone help me?

Comment: "something like" Why do none of your questions actually ask concrete questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this mousewheel plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs) and then:

```
$('.page').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    event.preventDefault(); // if you want to prevent the window from scrolling

    $(this).animate({left: (delta>0 ? '+' : '-')+'40px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect up and down scrolling with the native `scroll()` jQuery function like so:

```
var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0;

$('#div').scroll(function () {
    currentScrollTop = $('#div').scrollTop();
    if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop) {
        // UP
    } else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop) {
        // DOWN
    }
    tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;                   
}
```

Taken from the comments in http://api.jquery.com/scroll/